# How to change the language in timespan() function in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, date, timestamp, blogs, timespan

Im using codeigniter to pull blog posts from my database and I want to display how much time has elapsed since the post is posted. By default codeigniters timespan() function is displaying for example:

1 Year, 10 Months, 2 Weeks, 5 Days, 10 Hours, 16 Minutes

but i want to translate the words Year,Months,Weeks,Days,Hours,Minutes in other language, for example Bosnian,Croatian or Serbian.

How can I translate it?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it maybe works when you use plain PHP, i tried but didn't work for me in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You need to go to the application/language/english folder and create a file called date_lang.php. In my case I just want to have one language on my website, so i made the file in the default (english) folder. If you have more languages you can change the language in the application/config/config.php and change the $config['language'] = 'english' to whatever language you made in the application/language/YOURLANGUAGE.php file.

I added this piece of code in my date_lang.php file and it works well.

```
<?php
$lang['date_year'] = 'Godinu';
$lang['date_years'] = 'Godina';
$lang['date_month'] = 'Mjesec';
$lang['date_months'] = 'Mjeseci';
$lang['date_week'] = 'Sedmica';
$lang['date_weeks'] = 'Sedmice';
$lang['date_day'] = 'Dan';
$lang['date_days'] = 'Dana';
$lang['date_hour'] = 'Sat';
$lang['date_hours'] = 'Sat';
$lang['date_minute'] = 'Minute';
$lang['date_minutes'] = 'Minuta';
$lang['date_second'] = 'Sekundu';
$lang['date_seconds'] = 'Sekunde';
?>
```